# Algorithm ..to find nearest Neighboring Rectangles ..in all 4 directions

Tags: algorithm, spatial

Which Spatial Search Algorithm..would  help in querying the nearest neighboring rectangle ..for a Given Rectangle ..in all 4 directions(ie Top ,Left,Bottom ,Right).

1: The distance is orthogonal from one side of the rectangle..to the opposite side of the other rect.

2: Rectangles actually  represent  GUI components on a form.

Comment: That's not clear, what kind of distance? You mean orthogonal distance from a side of original rectangle to another one?

Comment: You are going to have to be a lot more specific.  Are all of your rectangles adjacent to four neighbors (on an infinite plane, or with some edge cases?)?  Are there gaps between the rectangles?  If the latter, what exactly does "nearest neighboring ... in a direction" mean to you?

Comment: The question makes a lot more sense now - please don't close it.

Comment: Still not really clear. What are you trying to *do*? My best guess is that you want to find the nearest "other" element in the cardinal directions for the purposes of presumably for keyboard navigation or tab switching. If you said as much this would be much easier to answer.

Comment: are you trying to implement r-trees using MBRs?

Answer (score 0):

Doing it OOP style in java, assuming axis that start from lower left corner and increasing:

```
class Displacement
{
  float top, bottom, left, right;
  Rectangle r;

  Displacement(Rectangle r)
  {
    this.r = r;

    top = Math.max(r.y1, r.y2);
    bottom = Math.min(r.y1, r.y2);
    left = Math.min(r.x1, r.x2);
    right = Math.max(r.x1, r.x2);
  }

  float minDistance(Displacement d)
  {
    float min = 10000.0f;

    if (Math.abs(top - d.bottom) < min)
      min = Math.abs(top - d.bottom);
    if (Math.abs(bottom - d.top) < min)
      min = Math.abs(bottom - d.top;
    if (Math.abs(left - d.right) < min)
      min = Math.abs(left - d.right);
    if (Math.abs(right - d.left) < min)
      min = Math.abs(right - d.left);

    return min;
  }
}
```

So now you have an object that instantiated with a rectangle calculates the minimal and maximals spans of the rectangle, this `Displacement` object is able to find the minimum distance with another `Displacement` thanks to `minDistance(...)`

Now you can easily do something like that:

```
class DistanceFinder
{
  ArrayList<Displacement> displs = new ArrayList<Displacement>();

  void addRect(Rectangle r)
  {
    displs.add(new Displacement(r));
  }

  Rectangle findNearest(Rectangle r)
  {
     Displacement current = new Displacement(r);
     Displacement nearest = null;
     float min = 10000.0f

     for (Displacement d : displs)
     {
       float curDist = current.minDistance(d);

       if (curDist < min)
       {
         nearest = d;
         min = curDist;
       }
     }
     return current;
  }
}
```

I wrote it in Java just to give a quick example but the approach can be the same in every language..

you can easily treat every direction in a different way by splitting the way you calculate distance over different cartinal directions, so you can do the same work I did in previous snippet but splitted for every axis.